# Filter response from json with php

Tags: php, json

for example, i have json result like this

```
[
    {
      "title": "x1",
      "url": "domain.com"
    },
    {
      "title": "x2",
      "url": "example.com/"
    },
    {
      "title": "x3",
      "url": "site.com/cam"
    },
]
```

The result of json will be randomly, i want to scrape ['x']['url'] path from that json, but the value of ['url'] must be "site.com/cam", and as you know, the results from json will change randomly, so I do not know which json path with value is "site.com/cam".

is there any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: by "scrape", you mean remove?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $index = array_search('site.com/cam',array_column(json_decode($json),'url'));
```

Sandbox

https://3v4l.org/72tsZ

Output

```
  $index = 2
```

Oh and there is a typo in your JSON

```
    },  <-- remove comma here.
]
```